# Session cookie for multiple domains. Security concerns

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-sessions

I think this is kind of a trivial question, but I got an idea that I want to share and ask if it is even necessary.

I have 3 react apps as 3 different subdomains - `auth.site.com`, `client.site.com` and `admin.site.com`, and a django backend at `api.site.com`.

##### Now it works like this:

1. User logins from `auth`, through `api.site.com`
2. Django sets session cookie with `Domain=.site.com`
3. User is redirected to the allowed react app (`client` or `admin`)

But... This way I can't set the cookie to specific react app subdomain, because `Set-Cookie` header is sent from `api` and browser rejects it if domain is not `.site.com`

##### Second approach:

1. User logins at `auth`
2. User is redirected to, for example `admin.site.com/internal/setcookie/<long_long_token>`
   (web server sends these `/internal/*` paths to django instead of react)
3. At that view, django gets the session from this one-time `<long_long_token>`, and sets the cookie with `Domain=admin.site.com`.
4. User is redirected to `/`

##### Considerations

First of all, I wonder if can I even use this, will the browser not send cookies to `api.site.com` when session cookie has a `Domain=admin.site.com`?

Also, I don't like that if user logins and is redirected to `client`, he can still just change subdomain to `admin` and will still have access (right now I have strong permission protection from this).

And finally, I hate that if I login at `client`, and then login to `admin` as another user, session at `client` will not work anymore because the cookie was overridden...